# Dogs and cane toads

Tags: dogs, behavior, training, psychology

Our dog is five months old, and we often take him for walks at night. We live in Australia, so often at night, especially after rain, there are lots of cane toads out. I know that cane toads give off toxins that can be fatal for dogs, especially if ingested.

This is problematic because, of course, our dog consistently tries to chase after them, presumably to eat them or similar. We pull him back, but it’s possible that he might eventually get one. How can we prevent this happening? We have him on a lead, of course, but is there anything we can do to show him that he shouldn’t eat them, short of letting him figure it by trial and error?

Comment: I do not know anything special about this toads. But in nature it is common, to use toxins with "notable" other things (smell, taste). Because toxins are only useful (in self defence) if the predator could notice it before the prey is dead.